# Syntax Highlighted Diffs

Tags: git, git-diff

How to make Git display diffs in the terminal with code syntax highlight, like what [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1932-syntax-highlighted-diffs) does? I mean not only with green for addition and red for deletion, but also with code syntax highlighting.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible with the primitive tools that Git offers.  You may be looking to upgrade to a more fully-featured diff tool instead.

Answer (score 18):

I recently wrote a tool that does this: https://github.com/dandavison/delta

Comment: Man, you are hero!

Comment: This is really neat. It seems like delta needs to be configured with git via `.gitconfig`. Can delta be used standalone?

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury yes, every option in git config is also available as a command line flag. Take a look at `delta --help`. If it's `--foo-bar` on the command line then it's `foo-bar` in gitconfig.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to write a git diff driver that passes the files through Pygments' `pygmentize` tool.

First, define a `pygmentize` wrapper with your preferred pygmentize settings (formatter / style / filters) in `~/bin/pygmentize-term`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec pygmentize -f terminal256 -O bg=dark,style=trac "$@"
```

Then, define a generic "diff with syntax highlighting" program in `~/bin/hldiff`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# Diff two files with syntax highlighting using pygmentize.

# pygmentize-term should be a pygmentize wrapper with your preferred
# pygmentize settings (formatter / style / filters)

function prepare() {
    local fn=$1

    # Work around https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1437
    if [[ "$fn" == /dev/null ]]
    then
        return
    fi

    local lexer
    lexer=$(pygmentize -N "$fn")
    #printf "Detected lexer of %q as %q\n" "$fn" "$lexer" 1>&2

    if [[ "$lexer" == text ]]
    then
        expand "$fn" | pygmentize-term -g
    else
        expand "$fn" | pygmentize-term -l "$lexer"
    fi
}

# Use colordiff (instead of diff --color=always) solely because it
# produces consistent formatting on a per-line basis, saving us from
# having to keep track of state across lines
diff=(colordiff --color=yes)

for arg in "$@"
do
    if [[ $arg == -* ]]
    then
        diff+=("$arg")
    else
        exec {fd}< <(prepare "$arg")
        diff+=(/dev/fd/$fd)
    fi
done

sed=(
    sed
    # replace "all attributes off" (used by Pygmentize to turn off
    # bold) with "normal intensity"
    -e 's/\x1b\[00m/\x1b[22m/g'

    # Replace colordiff's foreground colors with some dark background
    # colors. You can customize them here.
    -e 's/^\x1b\[0;36m/\x1b[0;36;48;5;23m/' # cyan
    -e 's/^\x1b\[0;31m/\x1b[0;31;48;5;52m/' # red
    -e 's/^\x1b\[0;32m/\x1b[0;32;48;5;22m/' # green

    # Extend background color across the entire terminal window width
    -e 's/\x1b\[0;0m$/\x1b\[K\x1b[0m/'
)

"${diff[@]}" | "${sed[@]}"
```

The above can be used instead of `diff` to get a diff of two files with syntax highlighting.

To get git to use it, define a git diff driver wrapper for the above in `~/bin/git-hldiff-driver`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# Program suitable for GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF, which will syntax-highlight differences.

hldiff -u "$2" "$5" || true
```

You can now set `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` to the above wrapper script to get git to show diffs with syntax highlighting:

```
$ GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=~/bin/git-hldiff-driver git diff
```

To get `git show` to use it, you need to specify the `--ext-diff` switch:

```
$ GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=~/bin/git-hldiff-driver git show --ext-diff
```

Note that by default `git show` will send its output through a pager (`less`), which will cause the background color to not be displayed quite properly, so also add `--no-pager` to prevent that.

Answer (score 4):

Code Syntax highlighting is not available directly with git.
What is available is summarized in "[Vive la git diff!](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306051114/http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/06/git-diff/) ", with utilities like:

```
$ git diff ‐‐color-words
# or
$ git diff | ~/src/git/contrib/diff-hightlight/diff-highlight

It was the best of times,
-it was the **blu**rst of times.
+it was the **wo**rst of times.
```

(the `**xx**` part are actually colored)

But those highlights don't depend on the language itself.
Even more sophisticated extension like [git `diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) are still about coloring the diff hunks, not code syntax.

[poke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537647/syntax-highlighted-diffs/37538282?noredirect=1#comment62566313_37538282) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537647/syntax-highlighted-diffs/37538282?noredirect=1#comment62566313_37538282) the diff tool [semanticmerge.com](https://semanticmerge.com/), which knows more about the language of the files being diffed: see its [configuration with git](https://www.semanticmerge.com/documentation/how-to-configure/semanticmerge-configuration-guide.shtml).

Comment: And of course there’s a bunch of diff/merge tools you can use, some of which are more specialized about actual language, e.g. http://semanticmerge.com/

Comment: It remains the question how much readable a diff will be when syntax highlighting get's applied. At least in the terminal, having a pretty limited color table. Green for additions and red for deletions sounds more reasonable for me.

Comment: @poke True.  I don't know "a bunch", but this one is derived from the PlasticSCM tool: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2013/07/semanticmerge-goes-visual.html

Comment: @VonC Well, most “better” graphical diff tools do offer some kind of syntax highlighting (although it’s toned down to still focus on the diff). For example [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_list) or [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/comparing-text-files.en#syntax).

Comment: @poke Nice, I don't use that feature enough myself.

Comment: @VonC, I tried [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org) and [fancydiff](https://github.com/da-x/fancydiff), but they both do not work out of the box as they claim.

Comment: @fossilet they would not do code syntax highlight anyway. Try sematicmerge, Beyond Compare or Araxis Merge instead.

Comment: @VonC I want to use this feature in the Git command line, rather not standalone commercial apps.

Answer (score 0):

Enable syntax highlighting in `vim`, then pipe git diff through the vim less macro, e.g.,

`git diff | /usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/less.sh`

This is made even easier with `alias less='/usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/less.sh'`, so that you can do `git diff | less` and get highlighting.

Comment: That syntax-highlighted the *diff* for me, not the *code*

Answer (score -2):

Nowadays git supports this:

`git diff --color`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is inaccurate, `git diff --color` does not provide syntax highlighting.